# Unable play multiple videos in viewpager using pageradapter in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, youtube-api

I'm developing android app like playing multiple videoes in view pager using youtube. I'm not able to play all video. Only first and lost position videos are playing and other showing blank screen.

**here is my mainactivty code-**

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    // Widgets
      private VerticalViewPager viewPager;
      private PagerAdapter adapter;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  find_view_by_id();
  fetchVideo();
  }

 private void find_view_by_id() {

  viewPager = (VerticalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

  }

  private void fetchVideo() {
  .
  .
  ..adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),video_detail);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

**my adapter class** -->

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

// Widgets
private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
private TextView txttitle, txtexplanation;

// Variables
public static final String API_KEY = "xxx";
public static String VIDEO_ID = "";

private ArrayList<String> mTitle;
private ArrayList<String> mExplanation;
private ArrayList<String> mArrayvid;


// Others
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ViewPagerAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<String> title, ArrayList<String> explanation, ArrayList<String> arrayvid) {

    this.mContext = context;
    this.mTitle = title;  // title
    this.mExplanation = explanation;  // description
    this.mArrayvid = arrayvid;  //video link

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mArrayvid.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);

    txttitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
    txtexplanation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);
    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);

    txttitle.setText(mTitle.get(position));
    txtexplanation.setText(mExplanation.get(position));

    String[] videoId = mArrayvid.get(position).split("/");
    VIDEO_ID = videoId[videoId.length - 1];
    Log.e("videoid", mArrayvid.get(position));

    youTubeView.initialize(VIDEO_ID, this);


    (container).addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (youTubePlayer != null) {
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        youTubePlayer.play();
        if (!wasRestored) {
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to initialize.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("Init Error: ", youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
```

}

**my xml layout-**->

```
     <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

and **main xml layout**->>

```
      <view
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    class="com.example.inbridge08.videoswap.VerticalViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8.6" />
```

and also plz suggest any *lib or github project like this*. thank you